# renaming a drive in the files app

Tags: release-hera

How does one rename a drive using the files app in eOS? On windows it was a simple thing to do, but in Linux I cannot see how I do it. I named the disk when creating and mounting it, but under Files, it just reads 500GB Volume.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**GNOME Disks** or **Gparted** should help. For details, read the following page.

> How to rename partitions?
>
> https://askubuntu.com/questions/276911/how-to-rename-partitions